# send ng-init variable with $http.post , angularJs

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

How can I initialize a `$scope` variable using PHP so that it can be sent to the server later in an `$http.post` request? I tried with `ng-init` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="name='<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>'">
    <pre>
        {{result}}
    </pre>
</body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.post('post.php',{'var1': $scope.name,'var2':'test'}).then(function(response) { $scope.result = response.data; });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="postMethod()">
    <pre>
        {{result}}
    </pre>
 </body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.myVar = '<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>';
        $scope.postMethod = function(){
            $http.post('post.php',{'var1': $scope.myVar,'var2':'test'}).then(function(response) { $scope.result =      response.data; });
        };
    });
</script>
```